# How to display block an element and display in another div?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the youtube video and the video thumbnail. By default, videos are hidden.

I want to display related video on click the video thumbnail and display in the another div.

Below is my HTML:

```
<ul id="result">
    <div class="testt-1">
        <h2 class="t1"> Name Tags </h2>
        <iframe id="video-1" width="220" height="115" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2vwBkTRDczc" style="display:none;"></iframe>
        <img id="img-1" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/2vwBkTRDczc/0.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="testt-2">
        <h2 class="t1"> Yak Chews </h2>
        <iframe id="video-2" width="220" height="115" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/JQgFDi-vu1w" style="display:none;"></iframe>
        <img id="img-2" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/JQgFDi-vu1w/0.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="testt-3">
        <h2 class="t1"> tags </h2>
        <iframe id="video-3" width="220" height="115" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/I1K3lrSsde4" style="display:none;"></iframe>
        <img id="img-3" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/I1K3lrSsde4/0.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="testt-4">
        <h2 class="t1"> Yak Chews Bone </h2>
        <iframe id="video-4" width="220" height="115" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/yah872hDA8I" style="display:none;"></iframe>
        <img id="img-4" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/yah872hDA8I/0.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="testt-5">
        <h2 class="t1"> test </h2>
        <iframe id="video-5" width="220" height="115" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/PJQbuIarVgA" style="display:none;"></iframe>
        <img id="img-5" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/PJQbuIarVgA/0.jpg">
    </div>
</ul>

<div class="large-video" data-id="large-video"></div>
```

Video and thumbnail are listing using for-each loop by PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the video if the image is clicked.

You can use:

```
$( "#result>div>img" ).click(function(){
    var vid = $(this).prev().attr( "src" );
    $( ".large-video" ).html( '<iframe width="220" height="115" src="' + vid + '"></iframe>' );
});
```

Here is complete sample code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#result>div>img" ).click(function(){
     var vid = $(this).prev().attr( "src" );
     $( ".large-video" ).html( '<iframe width="220" height="115" src="' + vid + '"></iframe>' );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="result">
    <div class="testt-1">
        <h2 class="t1"> Name Tags </h2>
        <iframe id="video-1" width="220" height="115" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2vwBkTRDczc" style="display:none;"></iframe>
        <img id="img-1" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/2vwBkTRDczc/0.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="testt-2">
        <h2 class="t1"> Yak Chews </h2>
        <iframe id="video-2" width="220" height="115" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/JQgFDi-vu1w" style="display:none;"></iframe>
        <img id="img-2" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/JQgFDi-vu1w/0.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="testt-3">
        <h2 class="t1"> tags </h2>
        <iframe id="video-3" width="220" height="115" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/I1K3lrSsde4" style="display:none;"></iframe>
        <img id="img-3" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/I1K3lrSsde4/0.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="testt-4">
        <h2 class="t1"> Yak Chews Bone </h2>
        <iframe id="video-4" width="220" height="115" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/yah872hDA8I" style="display:none;"></iframe>
        <img id="img-4" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/yah872hDA8I/0.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="testt-5">
        <h2 class="t1"> test </h2>
        <iframe id="video-5" width="220" height="115" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/PJQbuIarVgA" style="display:none;"></iframe>
        <img id="img-5" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/PJQbuIarVgA/0.jpg">
    </div>
</ul>
<div class="large-video" data-id="large-video"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I want to display video in another div 
<div class="large-video" data-id="large-video"></div>

And don't want to hide image

Comment: So you want to add another div and put the video on it?

Comment: Under the image?

Comment: video and image is coming from foreach loop, so How can I use video in another div outside loop

Comment: Sorry I dont understand it. Where do you wanna put the video the image is clicked?

Comment: I have video and image listing using foreach loop. by default, video is display:none. When I click on Image then video will be display in another div which I have added after <ul> tag. But Image will not be hidden.

Comment: Updated. You can update the size of the video on js code. Please check.

Comment: thanks. It is working fine.

I have accepted your answer

Comment: One more query, When I changing video listing on select video category from dropdown, in that case, jquery not working.

Comment: If you are no longer going to use the thumbnail and will use dropdown(select) the jquery code needs to be updated as well. The jquery code will be based on how you format your html

Comment: HTML is same always, only videos filtered by category.

Comment: As long as the same format of HTML and no duplicate in `id` this should work just fine.

Comment: thanks, it is working fine. I have used your code like this: jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('body').on('click','#result>div>img',function(){
    var vid = jQuery(this).prev().attr( "src" );
    jQuery( ".large-video" ).html( '<iframe width="900" height="600" src="' + vid + '"></iframe>' );
   });
  });

Answer (score 1):

In your JS file you've to grab the value of the image src attribute of a particular thumbnail onclick and grab the div you want to display it to and then append video tag to the div where the video src value is the value of the grabbed thumbnail image.